# When I append a path, python gives an error

Tags: python, windows, sys, sys.path

I tried to add a directory path to `sys.path`, but it gives me an error:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\tamer\Desktop\code\python\modules")
```

```py
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use `raw string`, basically `r` is prefixed.
For this use case it should be.

```
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\tamer\Desktop\code\python\modules")
```

Comment: why to use raw string?

Comment: The problem is w.r.t. escaping the character

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\tamer\\Desktop\\code\\python\\modules")`

Comment: thank tou very much

Comment: @mostafaghobashy Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the V sign to the left. :)